# Making the sloppy time-reversal transformation precise

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, differentiation, mathematics, time-reversal-symmetry

I'm reading Harbovsky and Susskind's *The Theoretical Minimum* Vol I.

In *Lecture 3: Dynamics*, under *Aristotle's Law of Motion* is mentioned Aristotle's (fallacious) law $F(t) = m {dx\over dt}$. Later, time is reversed by "changing $t$ to $-t$" and the result is mentioned as $F(-t) = -m{dx\over dt}$. This made absolutely no sense to me. So I tried to formulate this in precise mathematical terms. The following is my result.

> Let $\tau: \mathbb{R\to R}$ be a function defined by $\tau (t):=-t$
> and let $\dot{f}$ denote the derivative of a differentiable function
> $f$. Let $F$ and $x$ be differentiable functions satisfying $F(t) = m\dot x(t)$ for some constant $m$. Then $F(-t) =-m\dot{(x\circ\tau)}(t)$.

**Question:** Am I correct?

Comment: I found the original statement by Susskind much easier to understand. What is wrong with it?  He simply replaces $t$ by $-t$ in his equation.

Comment: @mikestone I don’t like abusing notation. (And that’s a curse!)

Comment: How is replacing $t$ by $-t$ an abuse of notation? That the deriviatve of $f(-t)$ wrt $t$ is minus the derivative of $f(t)$ wrt $t$ s just the chain rule of elementary calculus.

Comment: First, one doesn't talk of derivative of $f(t)$. It is derivative of $f$. Second, (in sloppy language) the derivative of $f(-t)$ wrt $t$ *evaluated at $t$* is minus derivative of $f(t)$  wrt $t$ *evaluated at $-t$*. You can see how bad language can easily confuse.